# IIS express from command line

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

I've installed the IIS Express 7.5 Beta 3 and tried it on multiple computers (Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows XP) and on each one of them I get the following error when running

```
iisexpress /path:e:\onlineinvoices\
```

This is the error. It seems it can't find the applicationhost.config file. I've searched for this file myself too and found it in the AppServer folder of IISExpress installation folder.

```
Copied template config file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config' to 'C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\applicationhost201115151422496.config' 
 Temp configuration file settings error.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The instructions [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/) are pretty weird especially the ones that deal with configuration file. As a matter of fact it says that the applicationhost.config should exist in Users Documents folder but there's no trace of it there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem.

It started working after I ran IIS Express by double clicking on the `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`.

After that it worked when I ran it from the command line.

Comment: thanks mate, so you have to start it from .exe initially, then it works.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, launching iisexpress.exe one time should fix the problem. This is a bug that we will fix at the earliest opportunity. Using the /path option uses a temporary configuration file under the temp directory, which is setup to include the specified app. Without /path, iisexpress.exe uses the default applicationhost.config under documents and will create one if it doesn't exist.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a blocking issue for me now; I use SpecFlow + WatiN to run automated acceptance tests, animating Firefox to hit our ASP.NET web app through a web server to verify expected behavior.  Recently I swapped from Cassini to IIS Express, and all runs fine on our build agent from the command-line.  However, when TeamCity runs it, the server fails to start, throwing this error.